# How should I validate a user object being updated by another user in Laravel?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, request, laravel-5.6

I have a Laravel application where a superadmin user can edit other users.

Please mind that superadmin should be able to edit user's password too. 
Since I can't really show the password to the people ( it is hashed anyway ) I just show an empty input field for the password. What is the best way to validate this user object?

My form looks like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('update_user') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}">
    <input type="password" name="password" >
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

My rules in FormRequest looks like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $userId = $this->input('user_id');
    return [
        'name' => 'sometimes|required|string|max:255',
        'password' => 'sometimes|required|string|min:6|confirmed'
    ];
}
```

- The scenario is that superadmin edits just the name field and submits the form.
- Password is recieved as null.
- So the password rule gives an error.

I can handle this by unsetting the password value on the request if it is `null`. But I sincerely believe it is a lame way to do it. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: don't you need to confirm the user credentials with old password?

Comment: no I don't need it. It is a closed system and their boss will assign a password for the workers. And when they forget; the boss will assign again. It is a poorly designed flow but I don't have a saying on that matter.

Comment: @SühaBoncukçu I’ve added an answer that I think more accurately achieves what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49858314/102205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add an [“after” validation hook](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#after-validation-hook). This will allow you add a “sometimes” rule to validate the password only if it’s not empty:

```php
class UpdateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        // If password value is not empty, add the validation rules
        $validator->sometimes('password', 'required|string|min:6|confirmed', function ($input) {
            return ! empty($input->password);
        });
    }
}
```

If you then only want the validated data, you can called the `validated()` method on your request:

```php
$user->update($request->validated());
```

So if the password wasn’t validated (because it was left empty) then it won’t be present in the array returned by the `validated()` method.

Comment: This actually looks like a lot better solution than my current one. Also thanks for the explanation better than the docs about "withValidator" method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
public function rules()
{
    $userId = $this->input('user_id');
    return [
        'name'     => 'nullable|required_without_all:password,anotherfield|string|max:255',
        'password' => 'nullable|required_without_all:name,anotherfield|string|min:6|confirmed'
    ];
}
```

[doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields)

> **A Note On Optional Fields**
>
> By default, Laravel includes the TrimStrings and
>   ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware in your application's global
>   middleware stack. These middleware are listed in the stack by the 
>   App\Http\Kernel class. Because of this, you will often need to mark
>   your "optional" request fields as nullable if you do not want the
>   validator to consider null values as invalid.

[doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-without-all)

> **required_without_all:foo,bar,...**
>
> present and not empty only when all of the other specified fields are
>   not presentThe field under validation must be

You may specify other fields in `required_without_all:` if any other fields are in the form.

**Update**

If you have many form fields and want to easily specify `required_without_all` parameters.

```
public function rules()
{
    $userId = $this->input('user_id');
    return [

        'name'     => [
                        'nullable',
                        'required_without_all:'. $this->requiredWithout('name'),
                        'string',
                        'max:255',
                      ],
        'password' => [
                        'nullable',
                        'required_without_all:'. $this->requiredWithout('password'),
                        'string',
                        'min:6',
                        'confirmed'
                      ]
    ];
}


public function requiredWithout($currentField) {
        $requiredWithoutValue = "";

        foreach ($this->request->all() as $key => $value) {
            //excluding _token as it will be always not empty value
            if($key != '_token' && $key != $currentField) {
                $requiredWithoutValue = $vrequiredWithoutValue. $key. ",";
            }
        }

        return $requiredWithoutValue;
    }
```

Comment: I still need to unset the password value since it passes validation with a null value and tries to set password field to null but I will accept this as the answer. Because I couldn't find a better way. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't want to use 'required_without_all'  because then I will have to write so many field names. unsetting the password input value when it's null still my way to go with it. But yes, it resolves.

Comment: @SühaBoncukçu I am not forcing you to use the `'required_without_all:'`, but I think it is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works:

```
public function rules()
{
   $userId = $this->input('user_id');
   return [
       'name' => 'required_if:password,null|string|max:255',
       'password' => 'required_if:name,null|string|min:6|confirmed'
   ];
}
```

In this way you can validate both the fields separately. Empty request is not acceptable. It should have either of the two values.

Comment: Sorry but the question only includes a sample of the form. The real form is a lot more complex.